# decrypt binary file issue

Tags: encryption, mcafee

We are trying to decrypt a file sent to us that is using a newer key cipher and hash AES-256 & SHA2-256 and our public key.

When we get a small file of a few KB, we are able to decrypt, but when they send a larger file of few hundred KB, the file fails. they claim they are not doing anything different, and we have not had problems with others.

Using McAfee EBusiness Server on Unix..

```
  Decoding data....

  event 1: initial
  event 13: BeginLex
  event 8: Analyze
  File is encrypted.  event 9: Recipients
  Secret key is required to read it.
  Key for user ID "Dev Co. <webdev@dev.com>"
  event 6: Passphrase
  event 23: Decryption

  symmetric cipher used: 3DES
  event 11: Output options
  typecode: 0062
  suggested name: 
  tempfile: created 'pgptemp.$0000'
  event 11: Output options
  typecode: 1000
  suggested name: 
  tempfile: created 'pgptemp.$0001'
  event 3: error -11443
  event 2: final
  Error decrypting file '.../processing/973160_IDRIN.txt.pgp'.
  Corrupt data.
  error decompressing data

  exitcode = 32
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a more specific specifier for the cipher. E.g. AES256-CBC? And what is sha256 being used for, hmac?  What Kind of padding are they using ?

The largest thing AES takes as input for an individual chunk is (other than the key) the block of data and thats 128bits. If your small amount of data was less than that, I'd say you had an issue with your chaining mode ( which is how you actually use a function which only deals with 128 bit chunks to encrypt something else). However, if a file of a few KB decrypts fine, this is not your issue.

What kind of padding are you using ? Its possible it encodes the length somewhere and they are  overflowing it. However, off the top of my head I can think of no padding scheme that would do that. Certain message authentication codes (MACs) will encode length  ( .e.g CBC mac).

My best guess, though, is that there is a bug in how you are handling the files, not the crypto it self, and something somewhere is getting truncated. Without any details on what they are using for encryption though, its hard to say .

Comment: The Hash is SHA-2 256 cipher AES-256 and using zip compression. Key size 2048.  It does not appear they are using padding schemes on the key.

Comment: You don't use padding on the key, you use it on the data you are encrypting so it does not have to be a multiple of 128.  What are you using the  sha-2 256 for ? A a mac, part of hmac, key derivation, or something else ?

Comment: The SHA-2 256 is what the trading partner is using.  I do not know how they are using it - only that this is what was communicated to us. We have been able to decrypt this cipher before.  I am wondering if the zip compression might throw off the decryption-uncompression.

Comment: Its possible, if you encrypt the data and then zip compress it. I should point out thought that zip compressing encrypted data is worthless because encrypted data is essentially random and hence can't be compressed.

Comment: By the way your server appears to be using 3DES and your question asks about AES